# Compressed file ingestion using Flume

Tags: hdfs, flume

Can I ingest any type of compressed file ( say zip, bzip, lz4 etc.) to hdfs using Flume ng 1.3.0? I am planning to use spoolDir. Any suggesion please.

Answer (score 3):

You can ingest any type of file. You need to select an appropriate deserializer.

Below route works for compressed files. You can choose the options as you need:

```
agent.sources = src-1
agent.channels = c1
agent.sinks = k1

agent.sources.src-1.type = spooldir
agent.sources.src-1.channels = c1
agent.sources.src-1.spoolDir = /tmp/myspooldir
agent.sources.src-1.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder

agent.channels.c1.type = file

agent.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.k1.channel = c1
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/myevents/
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.codeC = snappyCodec
```

Answer (score 0):

You may leave the file uncompressed at the source and use the compression algorithms provided by Flume for compressing the data when it is ingested to HDFS. 
Avro sources and sinks also supports compression in-case you are planning to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote custom source component and resolve. The custom source can be used to ingest any kind of file.

Comment: Hi Ripon, Can you please explain your appraoch in detail. I understand using customsource you might be reading each file as an event right ? how are you handling it on sink side of it to write in to hdfs ?